# Angular 8 run dist folder on npm run start-dev

Tags: angular, typescript, npm-scripts

I am trying to run my dist folder directly instead of doing `ng serve`. For that I wrote a script in `package.json`.

`start-dev: ng build && http-server dist`

The problem is I want it to auto run whenever I save any file. Also it will build the whole npm again which is a very slow procedure. Any other method on how I can do it? And do it faster?

Comment: What about `start-dev: ng build --watch && http-server -c-1 dist`? This should prevent caching from server

Comment: I face facing caching issue. I mean when I save my code and refresh browser I don't get to see the latest change. I have to empty cache first

Comment: Why not run `ng serve --prod`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `--watch` flag when you run `ng build`. So the command will be `ng build --watch` to auto rebuild when you change a file.

To auto restart the `http-server dist/<app_name>` command you can use [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon)

With nodemon the command would be `nodemon --watch dist --exec 'http-server dist/<app_name>'`

You can run both commands together like this
`ng build --watch & nodemon --watch dist --exec 'http-server dist/<app_name>'`

The above commands will work together. Angular will rebuild the dist folder and nodemon will restart your server when the dist folder changes.

Comment: Is this going to be as fast as webpack in react?

Comment: That depends on the project. Using the --watch flag will mean that builds after file changes are faster as it won't need to build the entire project.

Comment: So when I run `nodemon --watch dist http-server dist` I am getting the error Cannot find module 'C:\Users\AngularProject\dist' [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: Does the dist folder exits?

Comment: nodemon is installed and I am using `"start-dev": "ng build --watch & nodemon --watch dist http-server dist",` On running I get `An unhandled exception occurred: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir `

Comment: So I deleted the dist folder and run that command again and it worked. But when I go to localhost:8080 I am getting nothing

Comment: I ended up needing to modify the command slightly to `ng build --watch & nodemon --watch dist --exec 'http-server dist/<app-folder-name>'`

I also noticed that the app was under dist/<app-folder> so I had to target that folder

Answer (score 2):

Like indicated in Chris' answer, you can automatically rebuild your app when using `ng build --watch`.

If you just want to serve the latest version of your app, you can disable caching from `http-server` (which is on by default), using `-c-1` option ([doc](https://github.com/http-party/http-server#usage))

On linux (use single `&` to run scripts in parallel)

```
"start-dev": "ng build --watch & http-server -c-1 dist",
```

On windows (notice the `start` command):

```
"start-dev": "start ng build --watch && start http-server -c-1 dist",
```

**Notes**

- Your browser has probably already cached the files dist before you deactivate the cache like above,  so clear the cache manually once. You won't need to to that after
- This solution will not reload the page, you have to do it yourself
- `http-server` does not support fallbacks, which might be a problem if you are using angular's default strategy. So if you were on `http://localhost:8080/module1/path1` and you reload the page, you'll get a 404.
  You need to reload `http://localhost:8080` and navigate to the correct url from the app router
- Depending on your `angular.json`, the output folder might be `dist`, `dist/projectName`, or `dist/projectName/browser`, or whatever you indicated

Comment: I don't want to open two new terminal. and without it the second command won't work. I am okay with two terminal on vscode though.

Comment: If you are on linux, it will not open 2 terminals. Otherwise use npm-run-all package

Answer (score 1):

Better you should install lite-server.
For install lite-server:-

```
npm install --global lite-server
```

then open the dist folder in cmd or terminal

```
lite-server
```

Resource:-
https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-server